# create portfolio and show error is ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at handleParseError (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:449:10)
    at /home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:481:5
    at /home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:342:12
    at /home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at /home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:433:10
    at /home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:308:13
    at /home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /home/dharm/portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this it is a great resource:
https://itsmycode.com/error-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported/

What helped me was to change Dockerfile from:

**FROM node**

TO

**FROM node:16-alpine3.12**

did the build again and worked!